# Using sscanf() function to parse archive file

Tags: c

I am writing a program that reads the headers of an archive file, and prints out its important data using the sscanf() function. The effect should be similar to the ls shell command.

An example archive file:

```
!<arch>
file1/          1445559998  17099 88    33188   4         `
one
file2/          1445485080  17099 88    33188   5         `
Two.
```

The first line is an 8-char "magic string" to identify the file as an archive, the second and fourth lines are the headers, and the third and fifth lines are the contents of the files.

The header maintains a length of exactly 60 bytes (after the ' is a \n char) by using right padding (the spaces).

From ar.h:

```
#include <ar.h>
struct  ar_hdr       /* file member header */
 {
     char    ar_name[16];    /* '/' terminated file member name */
     char    ar_date[12];    /* file member date */
     char    ar_uid[6]       /* file member user identification */
     char    ar_gid[6]       /* file member group identification */
     char    ar_mode[8]      /* file member mode (octal) */
     char    ar_size[10];    /* file member size */
     char    ar_fmag[2];     /* header trailer string */
 };
```

Now on to my code. For starters, I want to be able to print out the file names:

```
file1
file2
```

I have this code to accomplish this, except I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
void parseArc(int fd_ar)    // fd of archive
{
        struct stat statbuf;
        fstat(fd_ar, &statbuf);

        char buf[statbuf.st_blksize];
        char *filename;
        int where;

        where = 8;

        while (where <= statbuf.st_size)
        {
                lseek(fd_ar, where, SEEK_SET);

                read(fd_ar, buf, 60);    // read the header

                sscanf(buf, "%s/          ", filename);

                printf("%s\n", filename);

                where = where+60+4;    // 60 for header length, 4 for file1 length
        }
}
```

An obvious mistake is the +4 on the last line. Ideally, this will be replaced a variable containing the length of the file, as obtained from a proper use of sscanf().

My main question is, why am I getting a segfault? I'm assuming it's on the sscanf() function. I've read up on the function API, but I cannot figure out how I am misusing it. Thx.

Comment: Although the archive file header is a string structure, I would expect to use `fread()` to read the correct number of bytes for the header.  Beware of long file names — longer than 15 bytes, that is.  They're allowed but handled differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialized the pointer `filename`.  So `sscanf` is trying to write the string extracted from `buf` to a random location in memory.  Hence segfault.

Either make `filename` an array, or call `malloc` to allocate some space for it.

And it's generally dangerous to use `sscanf` with `%s` by itself, since you may get a long string which exceeds the space you allocated for the string.  That's a buffer overrun, and it will lead to needing an emergency security patch when your customers start getting r00ted.  Use something like `%42s` instead.

(You may think you're safe because `buf` is at most 60 bytes long, but what if it isn't null terminated?)

Most compilers should be able to notice that you are using `filename` uninitialized, and warn you.  (`gcc -Wall` will.)  Do you have warnings turned on in your compiler?  If not, shame on you.  If yes, and you got a warning but ignored it, shame on you.

Comment: Or, on a POSIX system, you can use `%ms` in the format string and `&filename` in the argument list and `scanf()` will allocate the correct amount of memory for you.